# Android Map Overlay not displaying markers

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, overlay

My intenetion is to create an application that acts as a guide. My first step is to get map, add few important places of interest and using LBS and Proximity alerts, notify on place of Interest and narrate something related to that place. My problem is, the markers are not getting displayed over map. I followed what is given in Pro Android 3 book. The code is below.

```
package com.project1;

import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class Testmap24Activity extends MapActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d("Check point 1","Check Point 1");
        MapView mv = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mv.displayZoomControls(true);
        MapController mvc = mv.getController();
        //mv.setSatellite(true);
        mv.setTraffic(true);
        mvc.setZoom(15);

       Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker1);
       drawable.setBounds(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()/2, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()/2, 0 );

       map24overlay m24 = new map24overlay(drawable);
       mv.getOverlays().add(m24);
       GeoPoint pt = m24.getCenterPt();
       int latSpan = m24.getLatSpanE6();
       int lonSpan = m24.getLonSpanE6();
       Log.v("Overlays", "Lat span is " + latSpan);
       Log.v("Overlays", "Lon span is " + lonSpan);
       mv.animate();

           }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code for overlay is below.

```
package com.project1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class map24overlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> locations = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private GeoPoint center = null;

    public map24overlay(Drawable drawable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(drawable);            
        GeoPoint grtgr1 = new GeoPoint((int)13.044101 * 1000000, (int)80.232723 * 100000);
        GeoPoint grtpp = new GeoPoint((int)13.044101 * 1000000, (int)80.232723 * 100000);
        GeoPoint grtgr2 = new GeoPoint((int)13.044101 * 1000000, (int)80.232723 * 100000);
        GeoPoint grtpt = new GeoPoint((int)13.044101 * 1000000, (int)80.232723 * 100000);
        locations.add(new OverlayItem(grtgr1, "GRT Coats Road", "GRT Coats Road"));
        locations.add(new OverlayItem(grtpp, "Panagal Park", "Panagal Park"));
        locations.add(new OverlayItem(grtgr2, "GRT Usman Road", "GRT Usman Road"));
        locations.add(new OverlayItem(grtpt, "Pothys", "Pothys"));
        populate();
    }

    public GeoPoint getCenterPt() {
        if(center == null) {
        int northEdge = -90000000; // i.e., -90E6 microdegrees
        int southEdge = 90000000;
        int eastEdge = -180000000;
        int westEdge = 180000000;
        Iterator<OverlayItem> iter = locations.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
        GeoPoint pt = iter.next().getPoint();
        if(pt.getLatitudeE6() > northEdge)
        northEdge = pt.getLatitudeE6();
        Log.d("North Edge", " " + northEdge + " ");
        if(pt.getLatitudeE6() < southEdge)
        southEdge = pt.getLatitudeE6();
        Log.d("South Edge", " " + southEdge + " ");
        if(pt.getLongitudeE6() > eastEdge)
        eastEdge = pt.getLongitudeE6();
        Log.d("East Edge", " " + eastEdge + " ");
        if(pt.getLongitudeE6() < westEdge)
        westEdge = pt.getLongitudeE6();
        Log.d("West Edge", " " + westEdge + " ");
        }
        center = new GeoPoint((int)((northEdge +southEdge)/2),
        (int)((westEdge + eastEdge)/2));
        }
        return center;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
    {
    // Hide the shadow by setting shadow to false
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The above two codes displays only Map with satelite view without markers.
 Can someone help...?

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Link's Code for that, it may help you.

[Map Overlay Demo](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing in my application and it worked well for me.

[you can see the sample here](http://androidgeekworks.blogspot.com/2013/07/displaying-mulitiple-markers-on-map.html)